# Include theme stylesheets after base theme stylesheets

Tags: 6, theming

I'm using Tao as a base theme in Drupal 6. However, The base theme stylesheets are being included after the sub theme ones which is causing the base theme to override the the sub theme. As a result Tao's reset.css is coming after my theme stylesheets. Is this correct Drupal 6 behaviour?

My subtheme.info file looks like:-

```
core = 6.x
engine = phptemplate
name = Sub theme
base theme = tao

stylesheets[all][] = css/common.css
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tao's issue queue you will find more info. [See Issue #1013440: TAO stylesheet loads last and overrides sub theme styles.](http://drupal.org/node/1013440).

In the readme file:

> Tao does not use the `all` key for any of its stylesheets and expects
>   that you will not either. Be specific - if the stylesheet is for the
>   screen, or for print, say so. Any stylesheet overrides your subtheme
>   provides should use the same media key as the one in `tao.info` for
>   the stylesheet that is being overridden.

Comment: Thanks for this, helped a lot. Still seems strange that a base theme's stylesheets would be included after the sub theme. I believe this is no longer the case in Drupal 7.